# Parsing tslint json with gson in Java

Tags: java, gson, tslint

I'm trying to use gson to parse the output of a tslint run (and presumably eslint is similar).

tslint json output is a sequence of arrays, one for each file, not an array of arrays which would be easy. Here is a fragment of one run:

```
[{
"endPosition": {
    "character": 8,
    "line": 122,
    "position": 4277
},
"failure": "file should end with a newline",
...
{
    "endPosition": {
        "character": 118,
        "line": 120,
        "position": 4250
    },
    "failure": "expected parameter: '$templateRequest' to have a typedef",
    "name": "src/client/ts/app.ts",
    "ruleName": "typedef",
    "startPosition": {
        "character": 117,
        "line": 120,
        "position": 4249
    }
}][{
    "endPosition": {
        "character": 1,
        "line": 2,
        "position": 10
    },
    "failure": "space indentation expected",
    "name": "src/client/ts/controller/AboutCtrl.ts",
    "ruleName": "indent",
    "startPosition": {
        "character": 0,
        "line": 2,
        "position": 9
    }
}, ...
```

The problem is how to represent this in a Java class where I use a GsonBuilder's fromJson method to parse the results. Using a class that implements List throws a JsonSyntaxException at the point where one list ends and another begins. It's not a list of lists and it's not part of a key-value pair either.

I may have to dig a little deeper into Gson but I would like a push in the right direction. Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Ok this is invalid json. A coworker pointed out this issue to me:

[GitHub: multiple files produce invalid json output #379](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/379)

Comment: Yep. As a hacky workaround, you can wrap the file in `[]` and then insert a comma between any brackets (chage `][` to `],[`. This'll give you valid JSON until the bug gets fixed

Comment: I just replaced the ][ with a comma and made it one big array. That worked

Comment: Good call, that's a simpler and better solution